# \footnote cross reference inside image caption

Tags: captions, footnotes

I want to reference several images to the same footnote.

These are the two images that share the same footnote

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \begin{center}
    \leavevmode
    \includegraphics[width=0.86\textwidth]{figures/bottleneck_resnet}
    \caption[Bottleneck Design of Residual Neural Networks]{Bottleneck Design of Residual Neural Networks\footnote{\label{fn:resnet}https://towardsdatascience.com/review-resnet-winner-of-ilsvrc-2015-image-classification-localization-detection-e39402bfa5d8}}
    \label{fig:bottleneck_arch}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \begin{center}
    \leavevmode
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{figures/resnet_archs}
    \caption[ResNet overall architecture for all network]{ResNet overall architecture for all network\footref{fn:resnet}}
    \label{fig:resnet_arch_table}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, with this approach my image is not being referenced and I get a '??'. I also tried with `\footnotemark` inside the caption and `\footnotetext` instead of `footnote`. The first would reference the previous footnote and the second does not reference correclty either. 
Where should I put my `\footnote{\label{fn:resnet}https://towardsdatascience.com/review-resnet-winner-of-ilsvrc-2015-image-classification-localization-detection-e39402bfa5d8}` in order to be able to reference it?

Regards

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `\footnote` nor `\footnotetext` can be used inside a float, but `\footnotemark` is fine.  I'm not sure how hyperref targets the footnote instead of the `\footnotemark`, but it does.

Note that the footnote may not wind up on the same page as the float.  However, one must call `\footnotetext` shortly after `\footnotemark` (before any other footnotes) for this to work.  Nor can one use the optional arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.86\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption[Bottleneck Design of Residual Neural Networks]{Bottleneck Design of Residual Neural Networks\footnotemark}
    \label{fig:bottleneck_arch}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{\label{fn:resnet}%
  https://towardsdatascience.com/review-resnet-winner-of-ilsvrc-2015-image-classification-localization-detection-e39402bfa5d8}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption[ResNet overall architecture for all network]{ResNet overall architecture for all network\footref{fn:resnet}}
    \label{fig:resnet_arch_table}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

This solution bypasses the `\footnotemark` process by using the optional argument and placing `\refstepcounter` inside the footnote.  It is more robust in that (A) is can handle multiple footnotes in each float and (B) it uses `\afterpage` to place the footnote on the same page as a float (assuming the float has a caption and label).

The one thing it cannot do is put a footnote on the same page as a [p] float.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\footpage}[2]% #1 = label for \pageref, #2 = \footnote arg
 {\ifnum\value{page}<\getpagerefnumber{#1}\relax
    \afterpage{\footpage{#1}{#2}}%
  \else
    \stepcounter{footnote}% cannot put \refstepcounter into optional argument of \footnotetext
    \footnotetext[\thefootnote]{\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\refstepcounter{footnote}#2}%
  \fi}

\begin{document}
\footpage{fig:bottleneck_arch}{\label{fn:resnet}%
  https://towardsdatascience.com/review-resnet-winner-of-ilsvrc-2015-image-classification-localization-detection-e39402bfa5d8}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.86\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption[Bottleneck Design of Residual Neural Networks]{Bottleneck Design of Residual Neural Networks\footref{fn:resnet}}
    \label{fig:bottleneck_arch}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption[ResNet overall architecture for all network]{ResNet overall architecture for all network\footref{fn:resnet}}
    \label{fig:resnet_arch_table}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```