# tnote in caption of figure using three parttable

Tags: threeparttable

I watch the [threeparttable](https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/threeparttable.pdf) file which can deal with footnotes in captions. And I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{threeparttable}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[]{first.jpg}
        \caption{second\tnote{1}}
     
            \begin{tablenotes}
             \footnotesize
             \item [1] three
          \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

So there are two questions:

1. The caption is missing
2. The position of the footnote is too left

Is there a way to solve these two problems?

Comment: tnote is meant to be used with tables. With figures, one would normally write aux notes for the figure en the caption, or perhaps even better in the text where you're already discussing the figure.

Comment: What are the aux notes? @daleif

Comment: Auxiliary notes. I see no point in adding notes to a figure. You are also unlikely to see this in any professionally published book. If any they might be using endnotes (if the extra text is not a part of the caption).

Comment: @daleif What is the name of Auxiliary notes package?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479128/footnote-cross-reference-inside-image-caption

Comment: @JohnKormylo In that way, the footnotes may not be on the same pages as the targets, so I looked for `tnote` to solve footnotes.