# Citation in figure caption: Footnote shown on list of figures instead of the page of the figure

Tags: citing

I'm citing a source in my figure caption but the footnote is shown in the list of figures instead of the bottom of the page where the figure is shown. I'm using \autocite if that matters.

If I add a short caption with \caption[short caption]{} the citation in my list of figures disappears completely from my work.

Is there a way to get my footnote on the bottom of the page where my figure is shown? Thanks!

EDIT: Probably related to that post: [Remove autocite citation from list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438114/remove-autocite-citation-from-list-of-tables?rq=1)

But I honestly do not understand the solution to the problem..

EDIT2:

the requested snippet:

```
\newcommand{\indextype}{apa} 
\newcommand{\position}{footnote}

\usepackage[backend=biber, autocite=\position, style=\indextype]{biblatex}  
\settingBibFootnoteCite

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{image.png}
    \caption{some caption \autocite[S. 123]{source}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: You can use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, but you may have to move `\footnotetext` to another page.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479128/footnote-cross-reference-inside-image-caption/479143?r=SearchResults&s=2|15.6055#479143

Comment: added some code! I've figured out how to do it with the \footnotemark solution, thanks!

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, please post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The optional argument to a `\caption` goes into the "List of ..." while the required argument goes into the float. If there is no optional argument the required argument also goes into the "List of ...".

```
\caption[list of entry]{float entry}
\caption{list of and float entry}
```

Comment: I am aware of that but that's not the issue I'm having.

Comment: @Sef From your description that is the problem you are having. Provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem The snippet in your edited question is no use (the request was for compilable TeX code).